# Custom query/report return type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am currently building a custom report builder using EF and MVC.  My query builder builds up the SQL and I can then run this query against the database using dbSet.SqlQuery().

However, the user will be able to select which fields they wish to return, potentially from different tables.

I am therefore unsure which 'type' to return the results as.  If only fields from a 'Customers' table were selected, I could easily return a list of 'Customers'.

I hope this makes sense.  Can anyone give me any pointers here?

Comment: Have you considered working with `dynamic` objects?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... not sure you are going to find a perfect solution.  The problem is you need to define the columns at run time.  Originally I was thinking you could try to use anonymous types, but you can't use anonymous types in method signatures.  [Here is an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461504.aspx) on dynamic objects as suggested by Dennis, but to tie that together with your idea is over my head.  Long story short I don't think there is an easy answer.

Here's an example created by looking at [this MSDN Artical](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx) on how to execute generic queries against your DBContext.  You might be able to use that, but you won't be able to keep your data types (maybe this doesn't matter for your reports?):

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    //Here blogNames will be a List<string[]>
    var blogNames = context.Database.SqlQuery<string[]>(
                       "SELECT Name, YourProperty FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList();
}
```